# encontrar la fuerza de atraccion entre dos masas separadas por una distancia

Tags: java

Deseo encontrar la fuerza de atraccion entre dos masas separadas por una distancia, este es mi codigo

```
      double gravedad = 6.673;
        System.out.println("Encontrar la fuerza gravitacional entre la luna y la tierra");
        System.out.println("Ingrese la masa de la tierra  ");
        double m1= fuerza.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la masa de la luna");
        int m2 = fuerza.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Distancia :");
        double dis = fuerza.nextDouble();
      
        double F= gravedad*m1*m2; double d2 = Math.pow(dis, 2);
        double res = F/d2;
        System.out.println(" la distancia  Entre la tierra y la luna  :"  + res);
```

El resultado no es correcto.

Comment: Yo tenia entendido que la constante G de la gravedad era 6.673E-11
¿Por qué pones uno con Double y el otro como Int?

Answer (score 0):

**Calcular la fuerza de atracción entre la tierra y la luna.**

De acuerdo a la Ley de gravitaciòn universal, "Newton dedujo que la fuerza con que se atraen dos cuerpos tenía que ser proporcional al producto de sus masas dividido por la distancia entre ellos al cuadrado."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder realizar esta operaciòn debes saber que G es la constante de gravitación universal y su valor es [image: G=6.67x10E-11 Nm2/kg2] la cual puedes definir como `double gravedad = 6.673E-11;` y `r` es la distancia entre los centros de los cuerpos en [image: m2].

La masa de la tierra es : `5.973 E24 kg`

La masa de la luna es : `7.349 E22 kg`

La distancia entre la tierra y la luna es : `384100 km`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder ingresar valores con notaciòn cientìfica debes definir los valores que ingresarìas mediante el teclado como `double`.

Esta es la forma como realizarìas el calculo, primero obteniendo el valor de la distancia entres las masas al cuadrado y posteriormente realizando la divisiòn y la multiplicaciòn por el valor de la gravedad, recuerda que es muy importante el uso de los parèntesis para forzar la precedencia.

```
 double distancia2 = Math.pow(distancia, 2);
 double F = gravedad*((m1*m2)/distancia2);
```

Este serìa el còdigo :

```
   Scanner fuerza = new Scanner(System.in);
   double gravedad = 6.673E-11;
   System.out.println("Encontrar la fuerza gravitacional entre la luna y la tierra");
   System.out.println("Ingrese la masa de la tierra en Kg ");
   double m1= fuerza.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Ingrese la masa de la luna en Kg ");
   double m2 = fuerza.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Distancia entre la tierra y la luna km :");
   double distancia = fuerza.nextDouble();
      
   double distancia2 = Math.pow(distancia, 2);       
   double F = gravedad*((m1*m2)/distancia2); 

   System.out.println("La Fuerza de atracciòn entre la tierra y la luna es :"  + F + " Newtons.");
```

Ejemplo de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]